# mostrar variable php en txt con onclick en boton?

Tags: php, funciones, eventos

*como puedo poner el resultado en el txt al dar click al boton? sin submit?
gracias de antemano por la ayuda*

```html
<?php



function generarCodigos($cantidad=3, $longitud=10, $incluyeNum=true){ 
    $caracteres = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; 
    if($incluyeNum) 
        $caracteres .= "1234567890"; 
     
    $arrPassResult=array(); 
    $index=0; 
    while($index<$cantidad){ 
        $tmp=""; 
        for($i=0;$i<$longitud;$i++){ 
            $tmp.=$caracteres[rand(0,strlen($caracteres)-1)]; 
        } 
        if(!in_array($tmp, $arrPassResult)){ 
            $arrPassResult[]=$tmp; 
            $index++; 
        } 
    } 
    return $tmp; 
}  
$codigos=generarCodigos(1,5); 
 


?>



</script>

<html>
<input type="text" name="verificacion" value="">

<input type="button" value="generar codigo" id="code" name="code">
</html>
```

Comment: Para hacer lo que buscas, tenes que usar Ajax, te recomiendo que leas acerca del tema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claro.
Este código javascript puede ir en tu mismo archivo html o en uno separado pero debes incluirlo en tu script en tu html.

Tu codigo php lo quitaria del html y lo enviaria a otro archivo, a ese archivo haremos referencia con la petición de ajax y desde ese archivo tomaremos lo que nos retorne tu codigo php y lo pasaremos al input en tu html, nuestro intermediario sera la petición de ajax en el javscript, no olvides que necesitas la libreria jquery para poder manejar eventos como click() y poder enviar información a tu input a traves del val().

```js
$("#generarMiCodigo").click(function(){
  //Con este evento detectas el click a tu boton y llamas a la función generarCodigo.
alert("me diste click y llame a la función generarCodigo()");
  generarCodigo();
});

function generarCodigo(){
alert("fui llamada.");
  $.ajax({
    url: 'tuArchivo.php',//este es tu archivo php donde estara tu código para generar balga la redundancia tu código.
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data:{
       longitud: 10 //suponiendo que quisieras por ejemplo poder definir desde tu petición la longitud de tu codigo generado este parametro lo tomarias en tu archivo php a travel del $_POST['longitud'];.
    }
  })
  .done(function(respuesta){
       //Si todo salio bien enviamos lo retornado al input.
       $("#codigoGenerado").val(respuesta);
  })
  .fail(function(){
     alert("Si fallo mi consulta de este modo podre estar enterado");
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<input type="text" id="codigoGenerado" name="verificacion" value="">

<input type="button" id="generarMiCodigo" value="generar codigo" id="code" name="code">
</html>
```

Obviamente este código si lo ejecutas te marcara error ya que no hay un archivo PHP, pero esta es la idea genral de la petición ajax.

Espero haberlo dejado un poco mas claro.

Comment: no deberías colocar múltiples respuestas, con la que ya te aceptaron de hecho basta, si necesitas agregar mas; entonces dale click en editar y escribe lo que falte

Answer (score 1):

Concuerdo con en que debes usar Ajax, los posibles pasos que te recomendaría, serian:

- Lo primero que seria sacar tu código php de la función, si la petición sera por ajax, no la necesitaras realmente si esa es la única acción que realizaras.

Ejemplo:
Tu código php

```
$respuesta = $resultadoDeTuCodigo;
echo json_encode($respuesta);    
?>
```

- Parar colorcar el texto en el `input`, yo le añadiría un `id` para identificarlo de forma mas particular y poder enviarle la información de la respuesta del archivo PHP, para esto usaría jQuery.

Ejemplo:

```
 function generarCodigo(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'url de tur archivo php en tu proyecto',
    type:'POST', //metodo para envio de información
    dataType: 'JSON',//La petición se hara por ajax del mismo modo se 
                 recibira la respuesta
    data:{Si es que tuviese que enviar algun parametro para la operación}
  }),
  .done(function(respuesta){
    //Si la petición fue exitosa tomaremos lo que nos responda el servicio.
     $("#idDelInputText").val(respuesta);//Con esto envias al input la 
      respuesta del servicio.
  })
  .fail(function(){
    //Si falla tu petición, aqui definiras la acción a tomar en caso de 
     dicho resultado
 });
  }
```

Espero te ayude.

Comment: me podrías dar un ejemplo con el código de arriba el del generador de código? no se mucho de ajax pero si entiendo tu explicación